# No remote repositories provide plugin in packed format

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

`[DEBUG] No remote repository provides org.eclipse.equinox.console.source_1.1.100
.v20141023-1406 in packed format. Only the canonical format will be available in
 the build.`

While building a eclipse plugin with maven-tycho I noticed that during the execution of the command `maven -X clean install` there are lots of message like the above one. I am using a target file and in the target file I am pointing to local repositories. Why are they generated and should I be worried or it's just the normal behaviour?

I searched on the internet but did not found any results with this message.